# How do I make Eclipse 2023-09 console output tab characters compatible with Excel?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse

I recently updated from a 2022 version of Java Eclipse IDE to 2023-09.  I've been using the console output via System.out.println to display columns of raw data delimited by tab characters, \t, that I then copy and paste into Excel for plotting and analysis.  Ever since the update, pasting the data into Excel results in the tabs apparently being detected as spaces instead, and I get a single column of numbers all separated by spaces instead of several column each containing 1 number, which can't be used for data plotting.

If I paste the raw data into a text editor first and then copy/paste **that** into Excel, I get the columns to which I am accustomed, but that gets arduous quickly.

I tried poking around in the preferences, but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.  What kind of settings do I need to adjust to fix this?  I want my old functionality back.

Comment: if you want to put data from your Java program into Excel, you might want to save it as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Eclipse, but this sounds as if Eclipse's output window is offering to the clipboard multiple versions of the data to clipboard consumers.  Excel is opting for a "rich" format and this is losing the `tab`.  A simple text editor cannot accept the "rich" format so will pick the plain/simple format.  I think of this as "cleansing" the rich text out, so you are back to a plain text.

I don't know how to configure Eclipse's window which is your question, but another approach would be to use a clipboard "cleansing" tool.

If you are a Mac user, try https://apps.apple.com/il/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987 which is a simple clipboard manager.  Using this you can "cleanse" the content to achieve what you want to do.  It is a slightly different keyboard action for paste, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Eclipse but this does not seem to prevent Eclipse adding HTML to the clipboard:

```
 Preferences > Run/Debug > Console > ANSI Support > "Put HTML and RTF in Clipboard"
```

You can workaround the double-copy approach via a text editor by using Excel `Paste Special` with  "Paste As:"  `Unicode Text` or `Text`. Then Excel will ignore the HTML and process the clipboard contents as text.